# How to I keep a list in a numpy array as a list when transforming it to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: arrays, pandas, list, numpy

I think I have an easy problem, but can't find a solution.

I have an array X_train with a list of strings

```
4    [visa, card, geldanlage, 74843e]
Name: Keyword_clean, dtype: object
```

Then I want to transform this to a pandas dataframe. I use the following code:

```
X_train = pd.DataFrame(data=X_train, columns = ['Keyword_clean'])
X_train
```

The X_train dataframe then looks like this

| Index | Keyword_clean |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | visa,card,geldanlage,74843e |

What I would like to achieve is, that it looks like this (the list of the array is still kept)

| Index | Keyword_clean |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | [visa,card,geldanlage,74843e] |

Any ideas?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert it to a pd.Series first:

```
import pandas as pd
array =  [["visa", "card", "geldanlage", "74843e"]] * 10
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(array))
```